# Where is the custom.css file in Google Chrome on Mac?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, browser

I'm using MacOS 10.8.3 and Chrome Version 26.0.1410.65. And i want try to change devtools style.

When put this code on Terminal:

```
 ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css
```

Get this error:

```
-bash: /Users/Baris/Library/Application: No such file or directory
```

I checked directory paths and really i haven't `Chrome` directory on `Application Support/Google`

Where is stored custom.css on my Mac?

Comment: This is outdated, please refer to:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21207474/custom-css-stop-to-work-in-32-0-1700-76-m-google-chrome-update

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use a shell like Bash and enter a path that contains whitespace, it will interpret the whitespace as the argument separator. For example,

```
~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css
```

will be seen by the shell as three arguments:

```
~/Library/Application 
Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User 
StyleSheets/Custom.css
```

Logically, these don't exist. When you use `open` to open the CSS file, it'll tell you:

> The files /Users/werner/Library/Application, /Users/werner/Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User, and /Users/werner/StyleSheets/Custom.css do not exist.

So you need to **quote your variables**, or escape the space:

```
open -e "~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css"
open -e ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User\ StyleSheets/Custom.css
```

See also [Quotes and escaping](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting). For the gory details, look at this post: [Filenames in Shell](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html)